# Laravel - Duplicate record to other database - eloquent model

Tags: laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I am trying to duplicate rows with a given product_id and a given cart_product_id from database mysqlProducts - table ind_products to database mysqlOrders - table cart_ind_products.

My models:

```
class IndProduct extends Model {
  use HasFactory;

  protected $connection = 'mysqlProducts';

  protected $table = "ind_products";

  protected $fillable = [
    'product_id',
    'name',
    'category',
    'subcategory',
    'description',
    'price_VAT_excl_per_unit',
    'price_VAT_incl_per_unit',
    'weight',
    'breed',
    'kind',
    'age',
    'bio',
    'grass_fed',
    'drying_time',
    'nr_of_pieces',
    'lifestyle',
    'part_of_animal',
    'confirmed',
    'saved',
  ];

  //an individual product belongs to a product 
  public

  function products() {
    return $this - > setConnection('mysqlProducts') - > belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
  }
}



class CartIndProduct extends Model {
  use HasFactory;

  protected $connection = 'mysqlOrders';

  protected $table = "cart_ind_products";

  protected $fillable = [
    'cart_product_id',
    'product1_id',
    'name',
    'category',
    'subcategory',
    'description',
    'price_VAT_excl_per_unit',
    'price_VAT_incl_per_unit',
    'weight',
    'breed',
    'kind',
    'age',
    'bio',
    'grass_fed',
    'drying_time',
    'nr_of_pieces',
    'lifestyle',
    'part_of_animal',
    'confirmed',
    'saved',
  ];

  //A cart individual product belongs to a cart product 
  public

  function cart_products() {
    return $this - > setConnection('mysqlOrders') - > hasOne(CartProduct::class, 'cart_product_id', 'id');
  }
}
```

CartIndProductController:

```
public function createCartIndProducts(Request $request, $cart_product_id, $product_id) {
  $ind_products = IndProduct::on('mysqlProducts') - > where('product_id', '=', $product_id) - > get() - > toArray();

  foreach($ind_products as $ind_product) {
    CartIndProduct::on('mysqlOrders') - > insert($ind_product);
  }
  return response() - > json([
    "status" => 1,
    "message" => "Cart individual products registered successfully in database.",
  ], 200);

}
```

I get the following error:
"SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2022-10-28T19:54:12.000000Z' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `cart_ind_products` (`id`, `name`, `category`, `subcategory`, `description`, `price_VAT_excl_per_unit`, `price_VAT_incl_per_unit`, `weight`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `product_id`, `breed`, `kind`, `age`, `bio`, `grass_fed`, `drying_time`, `nr_of_pieces`, `lifestyle`, `part_of_animal`, `confirmed`, `saved`) values (656, ?, Aardappelen, ?, ?, 0.00, 0.00, ?, 2022-10-28T19:54:12.000000Z, 2022-10-28T19:54:12.000000Z, 903, bjbg, ?, ?, 0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1, 1))"

I also tried the following, but also without luck..

```
public function createCartIndProducts(Request $request, $cart_product_id, $product_id) {
  $ind_products = IndProduct::on('mysqlProducts') - > where('product_id', '=', $product_id) - > get();

  foreach($ind_products as $ind_product) {
    $cart_ind_product = IndProduct::on('mysqlProducts') - > $ind_product - > replicate() -
      > fill(
        ['cart_product_id' => $cart_product_id, ]
      );
    $cart_ind_product - > CartIndProduct::on('mysqlOrders') - > save();

  }
  return response() - > json([
    "status" => 1,
    "message" => "Cart individual products registered successfully in database.",
    //    "data" => $cart_ind_products,
  ], 200);
}
```

This time I recieve the following error:

"Property [{"id":656,"name":null,"category":"Aardappelen","subcategory":null,"description":null,"price_VAT_excl_per_unit":"0.00","price_VAT_incl_per_unit":"0.00","weight":null,"created_at":"2022-10-28T19:54:12.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-10-28T19:54:12.000000Z","product_id":903,"breed":"bjbg","kind":null,"age":null,"bio":0,"grass_fed":null,"drying_time":null,"nr_of_pieces":null,"lifestyle":null,"part_of_animal":null,"confirmed":1,"saved":1}] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.",

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First error: `Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2022-10-28T19:54:12.000000Z' for column 'created_at'`, the table tou're doing the insert query in, is not accepting that date format for created_at. Solution: quickly set the date format to a more simpler format: 'Y-m-d'

Comment: Second error: `Property does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance`. It's an interesting one. I would use the dd() function "almost everywhere" to see what is in which variable. What you're doing now is trying to get 1 field from Eloquhent and you're getting an entire record